# Git - Fork boost with submodule

Tags: c++, git, boost

I've run into an issue that isn't clear to me how I can solve it.  I'd like to add boost to my project, and I'd like to keep a copy in our team's account so that we can all have the same version.  So, I forked boost via the instructions on github (https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) by essentially clicking a button.  I then added boost as a submodule using the appropriate git commands to the project.  However, I discovered that boost itself has a number of additional submodules in the libs folder that now don't point to the correct location.  It is looking for those submodules in our account instead of from boost.

I'd like to get a copy of all of these and freeze them at their current version just like boost.  Do I have to go through and fork every single one of these submodules manually?  Or, how should I have set this up correctly to fork boost and bring along a fork of all its submodules?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: "so that we can all have the same version"—find out what, specifically, is causing the problem here.  Submodule update gets you the committed version, anybody who doesn't have the same version has gone out of their way to change to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @ConfusedStatGuy,

You can use `git <command> --recurse-submodules` to perform your operations for submodules inside submodules. This will help you save time by Git dealing with all the submodules on its own rather than you trying to configure/make changes to every submodule.

Also, I think freezing the submodules to a fixed version won't be a really good idea for obvious reasons unless your project does not aim to upgrade to any newer dependencies any soon.

Please refer to [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) and [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) for more information.

Best.